# VueJS passing initial values to function in methods

Tags: vue.js

I have this VueJS code that has a `postdata` method that's linked to a button's click `<button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="postdata">Refresh</button>`

```
window.onload = function () {
    var app = new Vue({
      delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        jokes: [],

        joke_id: 1,
        dadjokes_id: 1,
        tweet_id: 1,
      },
      methods: {
        postdata: function (retrieve_data = []){
            initial_data = {'id': 1, 'model-name': 'Joke'}

            if (retrieve_data) {
                initial_data = retrieve_data
                console.log(initial_data)
            }

            fetch("\start-jokes\/", {
                body: JSON.stringify(initial_data),
                cache: 'no-cache', 
                credentials: 'same-origin', 
                headers: {
                    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors', 
                redirect: 'follow',
                referrer: 'no-referrer',
                })
                .then(response => response.json()).then((json) => {
                    this.jokes.push(...json['jokes'])
                })
        }
    }
    });
};
```

Since I want to pass some data to the function I've looked for a way around a bug it has. I've tried logging `initial_data` if changed. It logs a mouseclick

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1166, screenY: 216, clientX: 1156, clientY: 129…}
```

with the x, y position but that now makes the function fail. What's the proper way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a way to access the "retreive_data" object in your template code? Because you can pass arguments pretty easily, as long as you have access to them. Here's how to pass a simple object:

```
  <button v-on:click="postdata({ str: 'Hey'})">
    Click me
  </button>
```

And in your JS:

```
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  ...
  methods: {
    postdata: function(obj) { // the Object wie pass in v-on:click
        alert(obj.str); // Alerts "Hey"
    }
  }
})
```

If you can't access data in your templates, go and use a field in data to store the data you want.

Update: If you don't want to get the Mouse Event, but don't have any data to pass, do an empty function call:

```
 <button v-on:click="postdata()">
    Click me
 </button>
```

`retreive_data` will be an empty array then.